# Ruby:: analog of call_user_func_array()

Tags: ruby

Is there call_user_func_array() analog in Ruby? And how about create class from string, that contains class name. I found only with "eval"...

Comment: It will help if you link to corresponding documentation. Not every rubyist knows PHP.

Comment: Also, is there a specific problem you're trying to solve? Or just wondering?

Comment: A bit more context would help. Normally you'd pass a Proc and use `proc.call(...)` or pass a block and yield to it. Sounds like you're trying to transliterate PHP to Ruby and that rarely works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a dynamic method name, use `send`:

```
user.send("method_#{i}")
```

This, if `i = 1` will call the `method_1` on `user` object.

`Ruby` uses the terminology "an object sends a message to another object" instead "calls a method/function".

Comment: @Tass I've seen all kinds of madness when it comes to metaprogramming in Ruby (basing dispatch on a proc's arity in a DSL for example), I don't really think this is too bad.

Comment: I need get class from string too, not only method.

Comment: class from string: `"MyClass".constantize`

Answer (score 0):

To call a function given by *str* with arguments provided by Array *a:*

```
obj.send str, *a
```

You are correct to be suspicious of *eval.* There is almost always a better way in Ruby. To retrieve a class object with a string, use:

```
Kernel.const_get str
```

So, for example:

```
> class A; end
> Kernel.const_get('A').class
 => Class 
> Kernel.const_get('A').new
=> #<A:0x100360ac8>
```

I should add that it would not normally be necessary in Ruby to hunt down a class based on a string containing its constant name. In Ruby classes are real objects, so you can directly store them in collections, assign them to constants and variables, etc, finally calling a class method such as `#new` with:

```
(some expression).new
```